# How to change style/content of cell that is programmatically generated, using a checkbox?

Tags: notebooks, cells, boxes

I am programmatically generating some cells that have a checkbox along with some text. The following code creates a button which when clicked, creates such cells.

```
var = InputNotebook[];
Button["InsertCell",
    NotebookWrite[var, 
      Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Dynamic[If[sel, "Selected", "Not selected"]]]], "Section"]];
      NotebookWrite[var, Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Checkbox[Dynamic[sel]]]], "Subsection"]
    ]
]
```

When the checkbox is selected, the text changes to "Selected" and when the checkbox is unchecked, it shows "Not selected".

The problem is that when I create multiple cells by clicking the button and select a checkbox from any one cell, the change is reflected in all the cells. Is there a way to localize this change? And could this be extended to changing the styles of the particular cell where the checkbox is checked? For example, when the checkbox in a particular cell is checked, I want its background color to become LightGreen.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

P.S: I am trying to create a small Todolist application and therefore I require this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With) to inject unique variables into the [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic) objects. Try:

```
var=InputNotebook[];
Button[
    "InsertCell",
    With[{sel=Unique[]},
        NotebookWrite[
            var,
            Cell[
                BoxData[ToBoxes[Dynamic[If[sel,"Selected","Not selected"]]]],
                "Section"
            ]
        ];
        NotebookWrite[
            var,
            Cell[
                BoxData[ToBoxes[Checkbox[Dynamic[sel]]]],
                "Subsection",
                Background->Dynamic[If[sel,LightGreen,None]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```